# PDF of $Y=a\sin(X)$ when $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, density-function

I am trying to find PDF of $Y=a\sin(X)$ when $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^2)$.
I know it is equal to:
$$f_Y(y) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}\left( f_X(2(k+1)\pi-\arcsin(y/a) ) + f_X(2k\pi+\arcsin(y/a)) \right)$$

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(a^2-y^2)}} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \begin{bmatrix}
\exp\left( -\left( \frac{\arcsin(y/a)+2n\pi}{2\sigma^2} \right)^2 \right) + \exp\left( -\left( \frac{2(n+1)\pi-\arcsin(y/a)}{2\sigma^2} \right)^2 \right)\end{bmatrix}.$$

I want to find the closed form solution of this distribution that I can use for further manipulation.

Comment: So far all 3 posts of you have been problem-statement questions, and you have been reminded to add contexts and show efforts. Again, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: This time I provided the whole context. I hope you could follow it.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to square the exponent in your second formula. Then the problem boils down to finding a closed form of the sum of the form $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(ak+b)^2}.$$ Unfortunately, this does not correspond to any of the elementary functions and you will need an elliptic function (such as the [Jacobi theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function)) to describe it.

Comment: Thanks @SangchulLee, I have corrected the formula...